# Is it possible to assign a second "/" directory, as you would other environment variables such as PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint for this example.

As an example, I've extracted [geany](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/geany) and [geany-common](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/geany-common) into a folder using dpkg-deb. I attempt to run it:

```
cd ~/Packages/geany/usr/bin
./geany
```

I'm given the error:

> (geany:9716): Geany-ERROR **: 07:02:33.815: Cannot create
>   user-interface: Failed to open file “/usr/share/geany/geany.glade”: No
>   such file or directory

The program is looking for the (hardcoded?) location */usr/share/geany*, which I don't have because I unpacked a .deb file. Obviously using a package installer/building from source/directly copying the files would fix this, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Is it possible assign a second "/" to ~/Packages/geany/ so when Geany runs, it assumes that both "/" and "~/Packages/geany/" are the root of the filesystem and finds the files it needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do an overlay mount via [OverlayFS](https://www.datalight.com/blog/2016/01/27/explaining-overlayfs-%E2%80%93-what-it-does-and-how-it-works/) ([tutorial](http://blog.programster.org/overlayfs)). I'm not sure if you can overlay `/` itself, but you can probably overlay `/usr` & friends.

Another thing to try, without adding a second root directory, is to [dockerize](https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110) geany.

Comment: Of course you can overlay the `/` root itself, look at any OpenWRT/LEDE system. But your suggestion to use the full Docker where the OP could simply bind-mount or create a mount namespace with basic tools is complete overkill. @Phil such questions are better asked on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree, however once you build a docker image, you can share it with other people who have the same problem.

Comment: OverlayFS sounds like it could work, but I can't for the life of me figure out how. The first problem is the Geany folder is on the same filesystem as /, and OverlayFS doesn't support overlaps. The second problem is what would the mount point be? Let's say I added it as /tmp/overlaydir, that's not / so Geany would still be looking for  /usr/.... instead of /tmp/overlaydir/usr/....

Comment: It seems very feasible to put geany on another filesystem (even a loopback filesystem) to go around the first limitation.

Comment: For the second limitation, you'd have to create, e.g. under `/homde/phil/packages/geany` (i.e. it would have a subdirectory called `usr`), a directory tree with all the missing things that geany wants. then you'd overlay-mount it onto `/` so that they exist and are available in their normal path (e.g. `/usr/share/geany`).

Comment: @root Docker is overkill, and getting it to work with OverlayFS is much more convoluted than it should be for what I'd think was a simple task, but I'll accept your answer because using a union filesystem and/or Docker would work, and are likely to be the only way to do it. Thanks!